# Flow layout issues

Tags: android, flowlayout

I am using this flow layout class to arrange dynamically created `TextView` in multiple lines but i have got following issues:

1. The height of this layout doesn't behave as `WRAP_CONTENT`(as shown in
   image given in the link).
2. I am placing this layout `toRightOf` an another static
   `TextViews`(To,Cc). It leaves a margin in left equal to `TextView` width
   in every line(as shown in image given in the link).

I want to delete this margin when content switches to next line. How to resolve this?

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

```
 public class FlowLayout extends ViewGroup 
    {         
        private int paddingHorizontal;   

        public FlowLayout(Context context) 
        {
            super(context);
            init();
        }

        public FlowLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
        {
            this(context, attrs, 0);
        }

        public FlowLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) 
        {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
            init();
        }

        private void init()
        {
            paddingHorizontal = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.flowlayout_horizontal_padding);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) 
        {
            int childLeft = getPaddingLeft();
            int childTop = getPaddingTop();
            int lineHeight = 0;
            int myWidth = resolveSize(100, widthMeasureSpec);
            int wantedHeight = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) 
            {
                final View child = getChildAt(i);
                if (child.getVisibility() == View.GONE) 
                {
                    continue;
                }
                child.measure(getChildMeasureSpec(widthMeasureSpec, 0, child.getLayoutParams().width), getChildMeasureSpec(heightMeasureSpec, 0, child.getLayoutParams().height));
                int childWidth = child.getMeasuredWidth();
                int childHeight = child.getMeasuredHeight();
                lineHeight = Math.max(childHeight, lineHeight);
                if (childWidth + childLeft + getPaddingRight() > myWidth) 
                {
                    childLeft = getPaddingLeft();
                    childTop += lineHeight;
                    lineHeight = childHeight;
                }
                childLeft += childWidth + paddingHorizontal;
            }
            wantedHeight += childTop + lineHeight + getPaddingBottom();
            setMeasuredDimension(myWidth, resolveSize(wantedHeight, heightMeasureSpec));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) 
        {
            int childLeft = getPaddingLeft();
            int childTop = getPaddingTop();
            int lineHeight = 0;
            int myWidth = right - left;
            for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) 
            {
                final View child = getChildAt(i);
                if (child.getVisibility() == View.GONE) 
                {
                    continue;
                }
                int childWidth = child.getMeasuredWidth();
                int childHeight = child.getMeasuredHeight();
                lineHeight = Math.max(childHeight, lineHeight);
                if (childWidth + childLeft + getPaddingRight() > myWidth) 
                {
                    childLeft = getPaddingLeft();
                    childTop += lineHeight;
                    lineHeight = childHeight;
                }
                child.layout(childLeft, childTop, childLeft + childWidth, childTop + childHeight);
                childLeft += childWidth + paddingHorizontal;
            }
        }
    }
```

I am using it in my xml like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_relative_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/To_textView_wrapper_relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/To_textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/to"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

        <PackageName.FlowLayout
            android:id="@+id/flow_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/To_textView" />

    </RelativeLayout> 

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/Cc_textView_wrapper_relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/To_textView_wrapper_relative_layout" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/PhoneNo_textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/cc"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

        <PackageName.FlowLayout
            android:id="@+id/flow_container1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Cc_textView" />

    </RelativeLayout> 

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/Bcc_textView_wrapper_relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/PhoneNo_textView_wrapper_relative_layout" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Bcc_textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/bcc"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

        <PackageName.FlowLayout
            android:id="@+id/flow_container2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Bcc_textView" />

    </RelativeLayout> 

</RelativeLayout>
```